# Creating custom shader for Windows RT applications

Tags: windows-8, shader

I am designing a 3D game for Windows RT devices using DirectX. I have imported a 3D object from Blender in .fbx format and now, looking for creating a shader file (.dgsl) for the object. As I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8, Shader Designer is not available in this version but still I need to create a custom shader (.dgsl). Is there any option available other than Visual Studio 2012 editions to create custom shaders for 3D objects?
Thanks in advance.